The checkPostStmt function in checkerContext Clang is not able to detect the for loops in my test cases
I am working on creating a tool to detect parallelism in a function, I am using checkerContext, to find the for loop inside my function and then traversing through the body of the loop to detect any parallelism and generate a bugReport if there is no parallelism in the function. The checker code and my testcases code is attached below. I am not able to figure out why none of the debugging output lines that is llvm::errs() are not executed. Nothing is being printed on the console.
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/BuiltinCheckerRegistration.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/Checker.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/CheckerManager.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/BugReporter/BugType.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/BugReporter/BugReporter.h"
#include "clang/StaticAnalyzer/Core/PathSensitive/CheckerContext.h"
#include "clang/AST/Stmt.h"
#include "clang/AST/Expr.h"
#include "clang/AST/Decl.h"
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace clang;
using namespace ento;

namespace {

class DataDependencyVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<DataDependencyVisitor> {
  const VarDecl *LoopVar;
  bool &HasDataDependency;
  const SourceManager &SM;

public:
  DataDependencyVisitor(const VarDecl *LoopVar, bool &HasDataDependency, const SourceManager &SM)
      : LoopVar(LoopVar), HasDataDependency(HasDataDependency), SM(SM) {}

  bool VisitArraySubscriptExpr(ArraySubscriptExpr *ASE) {
    llvm::errs() << "Visiting array subscript: " 
                 << ASE->getSourceRange().printToString(SM) << "\n";

    const Expr *IndexExpr = ASE->getIdx()->IgnoreParenCasts();

    if (const DeclRefExpr *IndexDeclRef = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(IndexExpr)) {
      if (const VarDecl *IndexVar = dyn_cast<VarDecl>(IndexDeclRef->getDecl())) {
        if (IndexVar == LoopVar) {
          llvm::errs() << "Loop variable used directly as array index. No dependency.\n";
          return true; // No dependency found
        }
      }
    } else if (const BinaryOperator *BO = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(IndexExpr)) {
      if (BO->getOpcode() == BO_Add || BO->getOpcode() == BO_Sub) {
        const DeclRefExpr *LHSDeclRef = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(BO->getLHS());
        if (LHSDeclRef && LHSDeclRef->getDecl() == LoopVar) {
          if (isa<IntegerLiteral>(BO->getRHS())) {
            llvm::errs() << "Index is loop variable +/- constant. No dependency.\n";
            return true; // No dependency found
          }
        }
      }
    }

    llvm::errs() << "Indexing indicates potential cross-iteration dependency.\n";
    HasDataDependency = true; // Potential dependency detected
    return false; // Stop further traversal
  }

  bool VisitBinaryOperator(BinaryOperator *BO) {
    llvm::errs() << "Visiting binary operator: " << BO->getOpcodeStr() << "\n";

    if (BO->isAssignmentOp()) {
      if (ArraySubscriptExpr *ASE = dyn_cast<ArraySubscriptExpr>(BO->getLHS())) {
        TraverseStmt(ASE->getIdx()); // Check the index for dependencies
        TraverseStmt(BO->getRHS());  // Traverse the RHS to check if it involves the loop variable
      } else {
        TraverseStmt(BO->getRHS());  // Traverse the entire RHS if it's not a simple array subscript
      }
    }

    return true; // Continue traversal
  }

  bool VisitUnaryOperator(UnaryOperator *UO) {
    llvm::errs() << "Visiting unary operator: " << UO->getOpcodeStr(UO->getOpcode()) << "\n";

    if (UO->isIncrementDecrementOp()) {
      if (ArraySubscriptExpr *ASE = dyn_cast<ArraySubscriptExpr>(UO->getSubExpr())) {
        TraverseStmt(ASE->getIdx()); // Check the index for dependencies
        if (HasDataDependency) {
          llvm::errs() << "Dependency found in unary operator.\n";
          return false; // Stop if dependency found
        }
      }
    }
    return true; // Continue traversal
  }

  bool TraverseStmt(Stmt *S) {
    if (!S)
      return true;

    llvm::errs() << "Traversing statement of type: " << S->getStmtClassName() << "\n";
    return RecursiveASTVisitor<DataDependencyVisitor>::TraverseStmt(S);
  }
};

class DataParallelismChecker : public Checker<check::PostStmt<ForStmt>> {
  const BugType ParallelismBugType{
      this, "Potential Data Parallelism", "Performance"};

public:
  void checkPostStmt(const ForStmt *FS, CheckerContext &C) const;
};

void DataParallelismChecker::checkPostStmt(const ForStmt *FS, CheckerContext &C) const {
  llvm::errs() << "Checking loop at line: " << FS->getBeginLoc().printToString(C.getSourceManager()) << "\n";

  const DeclStmt *InitStmt = dyn_cast<DeclStmt>(FS->getInit());
  if (!InitStmt || InitStmt->isSingleDecl() == false) return;
  
  const VarDecl *LoopVar = dyn_cast<VarDecl>(InitStmt->getSingleDecl());
  if (!LoopVar) return;

  bool HasDataDependency = false;
  DataDependencyVisitor Visitor(LoopVar, HasDataDependency, C.getSourceManager());
  Visitor.TraverseStmt(const_cast<Stmt *>(FS->getBody()));  // Traverse the body of the loop

  llvm::errs() << "Data dependency found: " << (HasDataDependency ? "Yes" : "No") << "\n";
  
  if (!HasDataDependency) {
    llvm::errs() << "No data dependency found. Emitting warning...\n";
    
    ExplodedNode *N = C.generateNonFatalErrorNode();
    if (!N)
      return;

    auto Report = std::make_unique<PathSensitiveBugReport>(ParallelismBugType, "This loop can be parallelized", N);
    Report->addRange(FS->getSourceRange());
    C.emitReport(std::move(Report));
  }
}

} // end anonymous namespace

void ento::registerDataParallelismChecker(CheckerManager &mgr) {
  mgr.registerChecker<DataParallelismChecker>();
}

// This checker should be enabled regardless of how language options are set.
bool ento::shouldRegisterDataParallelismChecker(const CheckerManager &mgr) {
  return true;
}


Above code is my checker code Name of file DataParallelismChecker.cpp
// RUN: %clang_analyze_cc1 -analyzer-checker=example.DataParallelismChecker -isystem /usr/include -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include -verify %s
#include <math.h> 

void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int j=i;
    }
}

void test1() {
  int arr[100];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 1;  // No warning because of the dependency
  }
}
void test2(float* data, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        data[i] = sin(data[i]) + cos(data[i]);   // expected-warning{{This loop can be parallelized}}
    }
}

void test3(float* data, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (data[i] > 0) {
            data[i] = sqrt(data[i]);  // expected-warning{{This loop can be parallelized}}
        }
    }
}
void test4() {
  int arr[100];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    arr[i] = i * i;  // expected-warning{{This loop can be parallelized}}
  }
}

void compute(float* data, int N) {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    data[i] = sin(data[i]) + cos(data[i]);  // expected-warning{{This loop can be parallelized}}
  }
}

void non_parallel_loop(float* data, int N) {
    for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
    data[i] = data[i - 1] + sin(data[i]);  // No warning expected due to dependency
  }
}

This code is my test cases Name of file data-parallelism.c
I want to generate bug reports when parallelism is possible
